# Permission to embed a youtube player in chrome app

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I'm trying to make my first chrome app and I have a problem.
In my first window, I made this html code.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div>Percebe ivair. Estou sempre por cima!</div>
<iframe width="640" height="360" src="https://www.youtube-nocookie.com/embed/aFMkXqrKGMY" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
  </body>
  </html>
```

But when I try to open the chrome app, I'm receiving this error message:

"Refused to frame 'https://www.youtube-nocookie.com/embed/aFMkXqrKGMY' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "frame-src 'self' blob: filesystem: data: chrome-extension-resource:"."

In my manifest.json I tried this:

{
    "name": "Hello World!",
    "description": "My first Chrome App.",
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "permissions": ["app.window.alwaysOnTop", "https://www.youtube-nocookie.com/embed/*"],
    "content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' https://www.youtube-nocookie.com; object-src 'self'"
}

How can I do to insert a simple player in my chrome app?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [CSP](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/apps/contentSecurityPolicy/#but) for Chrome Apps does not permit references to external resources in iFrames. This is different from Chrome Extensions, which are more flexible.

The limitations are as follows (as per the link above):

> - You can’t use inline scripting in your Chrome App pages. The
>   restriction bans both  blocks and event handlers ().
> - You can’t reference any external resources in any of
>   your app files (except for video and audio resources).
>   You can’t embed
>   external resources in an iframe.
> - You can’t use string-to-JavaScript
>   methods like eval() and new Function().

You can check out [this page](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/apps/app_external/) for more details on a couple of ways around these limitations, but below is the basic idea:

**Option 1:** You can use a `webview` instead of an iFrame, which runs in a separate process, thereby isolating the external content from your app data.

**Option 2:** You can create a sandbox page that contains the YouTube embedded script, and then include the sandboxed page within an iFrame within your page.